# I'm found a lot on this site

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, affix-riddle

My early part is very clean,
Use it to obtain a sheen.

My middle part is just a verb,
Very common, needs no blurb.

My final part is. Too right, is!
You think that's cryptic, well it is.

My whole all over PSE arises,
In all different shapes and sizes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is

> Sudoku

My early part is very clean, Use it to obtain a sheen.

> As mentioned before, "sud" or soap sud is a kind of lye or dissolved base chemical (something to do with  metal hydroxide? can't be arsed to go deeper into chemistry though). From what I understand this is the base chemical used to make soap.
>  From search enginges you get Sud = "froth made from soap and water" and thus can be used to create soap and "obtain a sheen" or in other words clean things.

My middle part is just a verb, Very common, needs no blurb.

> "do" is a very common verb. One could say it doesn't need a blurb. For the sake of rhyming? ;)

My final part is. Too right, is! You think that's cryptic, well it is.

> The cryptic clue here is about alphanumerics. "Too right" can be interpreted as +2. So from "I S" we get "K U".

My whole all over PSE arises, In all different shapes and sizes.

> All together we get SUD + DO + KU = SUDOKU, a type of puzzle that can be founds all over PSE in all shapes and sizes. The solution can be confirmed using the last clue.

Comment: Well done, you correctly explained all parts. For the first part, according to my dictionary it's not just a *kind* of <spoiler> but a general word for a frothy mixture of <spoiler> and <otherspoiler>.

Answer (score 4):

Is the answer

> Sudoku?

My early part is very clean,
Use it to obtain a sheen.

> @Smartest1here mentioned that suds is a kind of soap

My middle part is just a verb,
Very common, needs no blurb.

> Yes, do is a very common verb

My final part is. Too right, is!
You think that's cryptic, well it is.

> ?

My whole all over PSE arises,
In all different shapes and sizes.

> Sudoku is a puzzle in PSE and comes in different shapes and sizes

Comment: Suds is a kind of soap...

Comment: Noice suggestion!

Comment: I am not sure about the answer for the clue though, it is sud not suds.

Comment: The overall answer is right, although I'm surprised you got it from just the middle part! +1, but you still need to figure out the first and last parts.

Comment: Oku is a Japanese word expressing something mysterious.

Comment: @Randal'Thor is it "too right" as in ascii+2?

Comment: @Avi Getting warm ...

Comment: @Randal'Thor Too right cyqw